# jquery remove button in list don't apply to all boxes

Tags: jquery, button

I've a list with each li containing a remove button to remove it upon click. I'm not sure why but the button is only able to apply to the first item in the list but not for the rest of the li boxes. Wonder where i've gone wrong.

The following is my php code script and javascript

```
foreach($biz_watchlist as $biz_watchlist1){
  echo '<li class="biz_watch">';
  echo '<table style="width:100%">';
  echo '<td style="width:50%">';
  echo $biz_watch_details['5'];
  echo ' | <a id="remove_watch">remove</a>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<span style="float:right">'.$biz_watch_details['19'].'</span>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</table>';
  echo '</li>';
}

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#remove_watch').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow");
     });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#remove_watch')` is searching for ID. that is why you only get results for the first object.
id should be unique. if you want it in multi places change it to class instead.

```
 echo ' | <a id="remove_watch">remove</a>';
```

should be

```
 echo ' | <a class="remove_watch">remove</a>';
```

and then

```
$('.remove_watch').click(function(){
```

Comment: Finally, saved me from more hours of trying.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an id on an element that you are repeating on the page N times!  As per the W3C HTML Specification, id's must be unique. You can't have more than one element with the same id. If you do, then the operations on those elements are undefined, meaning that each browser will behave differently in this scenario.

Instead, use a class on elements that are repeating. Class attributes are intended for grouping operations:

```
 $('.remove_watch').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow");
 });


 <a class="remove_watch">remove</a>
```